# Function call dereferencing

Tags: php, syntax

Are there any plans to support function call dereferencing in php, as in

```
function foo() { return function() ... }     
$x = foo(1)(2);
```

?

I wasn't able to find anything on https://wiki.php.net/rfc. Does anyone have an authoritative link at hand (mailing list discussion, rfc etc)?

Comment: Well you can do it [like this](http://3v4l.org/h47cS)

Comment: [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net) send as a "Feature" request (if not yet exist) .. and to link this :)

Comment: I'm not sure that the readability of that syntax is particularly intuitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in [this RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) by [nikic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385378/nikic). Hope they'll get it implemented sometime soon.